# Unity error - Multiple Unity instances cannot open the same project

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

When I open a Unity project, this error sometimes appears and the project opens.
This error appears and clearing this window will restart the Unity Hub.
However, writing code or using Unity is not a problem even if you get an error.
Why does this error occur?

I've already tried reinstalling the corresponding Unity version and rebooting, but I keep getting this error.

Comment: do you have multiple Unity instances open?

Comment: Go into task manager and stop all tasks with “Unity Editor” in the name. Or better yet, restart your PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error occurs when you try to run a Unity project several times. Probably, it's one of two.

1. You tried to open the Unity project that was already open.
2. When you open the Unity project, double click to open it.

If this is the first case, do not try to open an already open project. For two, Unity Hub opens the project with a single click, so stop double-clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you ever double click?
If Unity runs more than one Unity, all but the first instance will experience a low error. This is what happens in Unity to prevent project synchronization from being misaligned. You can resolve this by creating symbolic links to the Asset folder of the project and the Project Settings folder. This allows you to synchronize what you edit on the first instance of Unity with all instances of the editor, but preferably not on any instance other than the first instance.